# Get adsense earnings PHP

Tags: php, google-api, adsense

I have to get adsense earnings of day with PHP. But after hours and hours of trying I can not get the "GOOGLE API" to work.

I ended up by getting csv from this URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-*************/reports
```

But this results in error

```
adsense.readonly{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }
```

I guess that I need to login before using that URL, but I can't figure out how to do this in PHP.

Can somebody align me on right way how to do this?

Comment: Start here, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started#setup, too broad for SO. If there is some PHP part you are having issues with ask about that.